# Ransack : Undefined Method "result"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ransack

I need to use Ransack and I install the gem and I restart my server and I writed in my controller this:

> ```
> def index
>   @q = Sound.search(params[:q])
>   @sounds = @q.result
> end
> ```

and in my view :

> ```
> <%= search_form_for @query do |f| %>
>   <%= f.label :title_cont %>
>   <%= f.text_field :title_cont %>
>   <%= f.submit "Search" %>
> <% end %>
> ```

But I have this error :

undefined method `result' for #ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fa185e9c2c0>

I try to found answer but all doesn't work.

Thanks for your help

EDIT :
I FIND my solution , i use an other gem : Sunspot and that work.

Thank's all for your help.

Comment: `Sound.search(params[:q])` already returns the results. You should use `@sounds = Sound.search(params[:q])`

Comment: @MrYoshiji That contradicts the [readme for Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack#simple-mode), would expect this to be a more common problem if that were the case?

Comment: @MrYoshiji , I use the Readme for Ransack for use the gem. And i dont understand your answer , can you explain more plz ? or make a demonstration if possible ?

Thank's

Comment: My bad, it was a wrong comment and I can't really help here, I misunderstood your problem

Comment: Are you sure your Sound model doesn't already have a method 'search' defined?  If you type `Sound.search` in your rails console, do you get an object type of Ransack::Search?

Comment: When , i type Sound.search i have an MetaSearch object, I think it's because i use activeadmin and in activeadmin we have MetaSearch.

Answer (score 4):

I have just had this same issue.

I found the solution here
https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/266

I changed

```
@q = Sound.search(params[:q])
@sounds = @q.result
```

to

```
@q = Sound.ransack(params[:q])
@sounds = @q.result
```

I think ActiveAdmin had overwritten my search method so, as explained in the link above, the ransack method has been created to run the search in case another gem has used 'search'.